# Illustrated child book with mushroom people

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to find a book I read when I was a child, here's what I can remember:

- It was printed in the 2000s or before
- I read the book in French, but I don't know whether I read it in the original or if it was a translation
- It was illustrated. The closest match for the style is the Voynich Manuscript
- The pages were part text part illustrations
- The illustrations were detailled and depicted houses in trees, mushroom women (people with mushroom "hats") and other creatures/plants
- I can't remember the story, I believe it was not set in our world
- The format of the book was A5 (14.8 x 21 cm / 5.82 x 8.26 inches)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. When you say "it was in France", do you mean that you read it in France or that it was published in France? In what language was the book? And do you know whether you read it in the original or a translation?

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post. I read it in french, but I have no idea if it is translated or not

Comment: Can you remember anything that actually happened in the story? What did the "mushroom people" look like - were they just mushrooms with eyes and limbs, or humans with very broad heads, or something in between?

Comment: Il was people with mushroom "hats" (I think it was part of their anatomy though)

Comment: "Tales of the Mushroom Folk" by Signe Aspelin maybe? The French editions appear to be "Les champignons animés".

Comment: Close, but that's not the one. It reminded me of new details, I updated my post